# Timex strings to datetime in python

Tags: python, datetime, timex

I want to convert a list of Timex date format strings (from SUTime) into normal datetime format. The problem is, that I have numerous different types:

```
dates = ['2018-07-09', 
         '2018-W15', 
         '2018-02', 
         '2018-04-06',
         '2018-W15',
         '2018-02',
         '2015-09',
         '2018-09-27 INTERSECT P5D',
         'FUTURE_REF',
         'FUTURE_REF',
         'PXY',
         'THIS P1D INTERSECT 2018-09-28',
         {'end': 'XXXX-06', 'begin': 'XXXX-04'}, 
         '2014-03-19',
         '2018-08-02']
```

I have two objectives:

1. Ignore all entries not directly indicating a certain date
2. Convert all other to a `'yyyy-mm-dd'` format, citing always the first day of the year, month, week, etc. E.g.: `'2018-02'` should become `'2018-02-01'` or `'2018-W15'` `2018-04-09`

I tried with pandas' `pd.to_datetime` function, but this does not convert weeks to dates

Comment: I don't know of a python date string parser that will automatically handle all of the strings listed in your example. You could use [`dateutil.parser`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) to handle things like defaulting the first day of the month when the string is "YYYY-MM", but you will likely need to add some of your own custom parsing to handle date strings with extraneous non-date text, week number strings, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit of a challenge when the data collection isn't uniform. I am unfamiliar with Timex and was unable to find any packages that might help.

This might help you out. I wrote some functions that handle each particular case.

```
import datetime
from pprint import pprint

dates = ['2018-07-09',
         '2018-W15',
         '2018-02',
         '2018-04-06',
         '2018-W15',
         '2018-02',
         '2015-09',
         '2018-09-27 INTERSECT P5D',
         'FUTURE_REF',
         'FUTURE_REF',
         'PXY',
         'THIS P1D INTERSECT 2018-09-28',
         {'end': 'XXXX-06', 'begin': 'XXXX-04'},
         '2014-03-19',
         '2018-08-02']

FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d'
def get_simple_date(item, strformat=FORMAT):
    try:
        return (True, datetime.datetime.strptime(item, strformat))
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return (False, item)

def get_from_split(is_resolved, item):
    if is_resolved:
        return (is_resolved, item)
    try:
        tokens = item.split(' ')
        are_resolved, items = zip(*(get_simple_date(token) for token in tokens))
        if any(are_resolved):
            # assume one valid token
            result, = (item for item in items if isinstance(item, datetime.datetime))
            return (True, result)
    except (ValueError, AttributeError):
        pass
    return (False, item)

def get_from_no_day(is_resolved, item):
    if is_resolved:
        return (is_resolved, item)
    if not 'W' in item:
        try:
            return (True, datetime.datetime.strptime(f'{item}-01', FORMAT))
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return (False, item)

def get_from_w_date(is_resolved, item):
    if is_resolved:
        return (is_resolved, item)
    if 'W' in item:
        return (True, datetime.datetime.strptime(f'{item}-1', "%Y-W%W-%w"))
    return (is_resolved, item)

collection1 = (get_simple_date(item) for item in dates)
collection2 = (get_from_split(*args) for args in collection1)
collection3 = (get_from_no_day(*args) for args in collection2)
collection4 = (get_from_w_date(*args) for args in collection3)
pprint([d for is_resolved, d in collection4 if is_resolved], indent=4)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[   datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 9, 0, 0),
    datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 9, 0, 0),
    datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 1, 0, 0),
    datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 6, 0, 0),
    datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 9, 0, 0),
    datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 1, 0, 0),
    datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 1, 0, 0),
    datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 27, 0, 0),
    datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 28, 0, 0),
    datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 19, 0, 0),
    datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 2, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks great.